# jquery table sorter - dd/mm/yyyy parser

Tags: jquery, parsing, tablesorter

After searching around, I can't seem to be able to make the first column sort by the UK date format - dd/mm/yyyy
Would anyone be willing to help me with this problem? Current js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("table.tablecontainer").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});

    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
               sortList: [[0,0]], 
       headers: {
           5:{
              sorter: false
           }
       }
    });
});
```

All help appreciated as this isn't an area I can class myself as proficient in at all!

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
    $("#myTable").tableSorter( {dateFormat: "uk"} );
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
    sortList: [[0,0]], 
    headers: {
    // assign the sixth column (we start counting zero)
     5:{
     // this is header 6 since the headers start at 0
        // disable it by setting the property sorter to false
     sorter: false
     },
    }});
});
```

Comment: I have revised my answer accordingly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally use the Jquery tablesorter script from [tablesorter.com](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)
with the dateFormat- property set to "uk".

```
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        dateFormat: "uk",
        sortList: [[0, 0]], 
        headers: { 5: { sorter: false}} 
     });
```

You are calling the script several times with different options, which confuses the poor library.

Only make one call to tablesorter with all the different options set as above.

I haven't checked the zebra widget, but the rest behaves as it should now.

Good luck with your endeavor :-)

Comment: @Guidehouse - unless it's time for me to go to bed, I can't seem to get this to work - amended code at the top of this post. Would you be willing to help?

Comment: @Motley9735 - After a good nights sleep. It seems to me that, your problem was actually how to call the script with several options, rather than finding the option for dateformat.
I have revised my answer accordingly. Hope this can help you:-)

Comment: @guidehouse - crikey, yep, a good nights sleep and it looks much more obvious now - the zzzz's always help! Thank you very much for helping me out here.

Answer (score 5):

you need to define a **[parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)** for this. Something like

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'uk-date', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        var date = s.split('/');
        return new Date(date[2],date[1],date[0]).getTime();
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
});
```

this could probably do with some better format checking. I'd recommend defining your parsers in a separate script to the tablesorter plugin so that you can easily upgrade. You would reference the parsers script in a `<script>` tag after the tablesorter script.

To use would be like

```
$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            1: { 
                sorter:'uk-date' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: tablesorter already have a parser for dates in uk-format, which does it like this s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");, so no need to define your own. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this dodges the question, but i might just configure the textExtraction option (see here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration)

you could just put a sortable date in a hidden span (class='sort_key' as below) and set something like:

```
textExtraction: function(node) {
  if($j(node).find('.sort_key').is('span') {
    return $j(node).find('.sort_key').text();
  } else {
    return $j(node).text();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

Set the date format. Here are the available options. (Modified v2.0.23).

- "mmddyyyy" (default)
- "ddmmyyyy"
- "yyyymmdd"

In previous versions, this option was set as "us", "uk" or "dd/mm/yy". This option was modified to better fit needed date formats. It will only work with four digit years!

The sorter should be set to "shortDate" and the date format can be set in the "dateFormat" option or set for a specific columns within the "headers" option. See the demo page to see it working.

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({

    dateFormat : "mmddyyyy", // default date format

    // or to change the format for specific columns,
    // add the dateFormat to the headers option:
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: "shortDate" }, // "shortDate" with the default dateFormat above
      1: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy" }, // day first format
      2: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "yyyymmdd" }  // year first format
    }

  });
});
```

Individual columns can be modified by adding the following (they all do the same thing), set in order of priority (Modified v2.3.1):

- jQuery data data-dateFormat="mmddyyyy".
- metadata class="{ dateFormat: 'mmddyyyy'}". This requires the metadata plugin.
- headers option headers : { 0 : { dateFormat : 'mmddyyyy' } }.
- header class name class="dateFormat-mmddyyyy".
  Overall dateFormat option.

In my case I have used

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({dateFormat: "uk"})
```

for the version.